# Moving average with changing window

Tags: r

I would like to calculate the moving average of a variable in R with a changing window size. To be more specific: The moving average should be calculated over three years, but the data (time-series) is available in higher frequency and the window size can vary for each three-year window.

Assume the following dataset:

```
library(data.table)
set.seed(1)   # reproduceable data
dataset <- data.table(ID=c(rep("A",2208),rep("B",2208)),
x = c(rnorm(2208*2)), time=c(seq(as.Date("1988/03/15"),
as.Date("2000/04/16"), "day"),seq(as.Date("1988/03/15"),
as.Date("2000/04/16"), "day")))
```

The three-year moving average of the variable x should be calculated for both of the IDs (person A and B). Can this be done with `zoo` and `datatable` preferably? But any solution is fine.

Please note I know how to do this with a fixed window size, the problem here is the varying window size.

Comment: What you mean by _the window size can vary for each three-year window_?

Comment: I think the OP means that the window will span three years, but that the number of observations within those years is variable.

Comment: If dataset size is not an issue, then create a data.table starting with min date, to max date and join your dataset, then you can use a fixed sliding window size.

Comment: @Lyngbakr that is what I meant, thank you. Unfortunately the dataset size is an issue, but even if it wasn't, the problem with irregular window size would exist, because in a given year there are not necessarily the same amount of days as in another one (i.e. in leapyears there is always a difference from normal years)?

Comment: Check out `lubridate`. The package calculates a 3 year dfference factoring for leap years. You could start by calculating a "starting date" for each observation for your window, and somehow filter on the current date and starting date and get the average value.

Comment: Unclear specifically what you want to do but `rollapply` supports a vector `width=` argument.

Comment: I don't know if it works, but what about `dataset %>% group_by(ID) %>% mutate(avg=rollapplyr(x,mean,width=3*365,fill=NA))`, As you already have daily measuerments without missing values.

Comment: If you're fine with a window of 1095 days leap year or not, you could also make the data complete by adding NAs then standard rollapply with mean and na.rm = TRUE

Comment: Also side note, your average will be biased to reflect periods where you have more measurements so the value for a window may not reflect its center.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand correctly the OP wants to span exactly 3 years. As this may include leap years, the window size can be either 1095 days or 1096 days.

This can be solved by *aggregating in a non-equi join* together with `lubridate`'s *rollback* date arithmetic.

```
library(data.table)
library(lubridate)
# create 3 years windows for each ID for later non-equi join
win <- dataset[, CJ(ID = ID, start = time, unique = TRUE)][
  # make sure to pick
  , end := start %m+% years(3) - days(1)][
    # remove windows which end out of date range
    end <= max(start)]
win
```

> ```
>       ID      start        end
>    1:  A 1988-03-15 1991-03-14
>    2:  A 1988-03-16 1991-03-15
>    3:  A 1988-03-17 1991-03-16
>    4:  A 1988-03-18 1991-03-17
>    5:  A 1988-03-19 1991-03-18
>   ---                         
> 6638:  B 1997-04-13 2000-04-12
> 6639:  B 1997-04-14 2000-04-13
> 6640:  B 1997-04-15 2000-04-14
> 6641:  B 1997-04-16 2000-04-15
> 6642:  B 1997-04-17 2000-04-16
> ```

```
# check window lengths
win[, .N, by = .(days = end - start + 1L)]
```

> ```
>         days    N
> 1: 1095 days 2166
> 2: 1096 days 4476
> ```

```
# see what happens in leap years
win[leap_year(start) & month(start) == 2 & day(start) %in% 28:29, 
  .(start, end, days = end - start + 1L)]
```

> ```
>         start        end      days
> 1: 1992-02-28 1995-02-27 1096 days
> 2: 1992-02-29 1995-02-27 1095 days
> 3: 1996-02-28 1999-02-27 1096 days
> 4: 1996-02-29 1999-02-27 1095 days
> 5: 1992-02-28 1995-02-27 1096 days
> 6: 1992-02-29 1995-02-27 1095 days
> 7: 1996-02-28 1999-02-27 1096 days
> 8: 1996-02-29 1999-02-27 1095 days
> ```

```
win[leap_year(end) & month(end) == 2 & day(end) %in% 28:29,
    .(start, end, days = end - start + 1L)]
```

> ```
>         start        end      days
> 1: 1989-03-01 1992-02-29 1096 days
> 2: 1993-03-01 1996-02-29 1096 days
> 3: 1997-03-01 2000-02-29 1096 days
> 4: 1989-03-01 1992-02-29 1096 days
> 5: 1993-03-01 1996-02-29 1096 days
> 6: 1997-03-01 2000-02-29 1096 days
> ```

```
# aggregate in a non-equi-join
dataset[win, on = .(ID, time >= start, time <= end), by = .EACHI, .(avg = mean(x))]
```

> ```
>       ID       time       time         avg
>    1:  A 1988-03-15 1991-03-14 -0.01184078
>    2:  A 1988-03-16 1991-03-15 -0.01317813
>    3:  A 1988-03-17 1991-03-16 -0.01179571
>    4:  A 1988-03-18 1991-03-17 -0.01006100
>    5:  A 1988-03-19 1991-03-18 -0.01221798
>   ---                                     
> 6638:  B 1997-04-13 2000-04-12 -0.03412214
> 6639:  B 1997-04-14 2000-04-13 -0.03604176
> 6640:  B 1997-04-15 2000-04-14 -0.03556291
> 6641:  B 1997-04-16 2000-04-15 -0.03392185
> 6642:  B 1997-04-17 2000-04-16 -0.03393674
> ```

Comment: thanks this looks perfect to me. Just one question: Could you also formulate this with the usual `merge` syntax from `datatable`?

Comment: No, the goodies like *non-equi join* and *grouping by each i* are only available with the `[.data.table` syntax. `data.table`'s `merge()` is more or less only  a faster implementation of base R's `merge()`. There is [a section in the FAQ](https://cloud.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/vignettes/datatable-faq.html#MergeDiff) which explains the differences.

Comment: I understand, thanks. I was asking because in my opinion the syntax of `merge` is cleaner. It's harder to remember the difference between X[Y] and Y[X] imho. But the solution is great, so I guess I need to get used to this.

Comment: Yes, `merge()` is simpler but less powerful. `X[Y]` behaves like a right join, i.e., take all rows of `Y` and try to find matches in `X`.

Comment: There is the package `fuzzyjoin` that could work as well and has syntax close to `merge` (and even closer to `dplyr` joins), but I believe it will be slower.

Answer (score 2):

As @A.Suliman mentions in comments your example data has a fixed window width, but let's assume your real data hasn't as that's what your text says.

The parameter `width` from `rollapply` doesn't have to be constant, so we can compute the width first, make sure we align the window to the left, and run `rollaply`.

```
library(zoo)
library(tidyverse)
dataset %>% 
  arrange(ID,time) %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(avg = rollapply(x, FUN = mean, align = "left",
                         width = map_dbl(time, ~which.max(time[time < .x + 3*365.25])) - row_number()+1))
#                          
# # A tibble: 8,832 x 4
# # Groups:   ID [2]
#         ID       x       time    avg
#     <fctr>   <dbl>     <date>  <dbl>
#   1      A -0.0258 1988-03-15 0.0109
#   2      A -0.0258 1988-03-15 0.0109
#   3      A -0.1562 1988-03-16 0.0115
#   4      A -0.1562 1988-03-16 0.0115
#   5      A  0.8193 1988-03-17 0.0115
#   6      A  0.8193 1988-03-17 0.0112
#   7      A -1.1136 1988-03-18 0.0102
#   8      A -1.1136 1988-03-18 0.0107
#   9      A -0.9336 1988-03-19 0.0105
#  10      A -0.9336 1988-03-19 0.0109
```

Comment: I'm in a hurry so didn't bother translating the syntax to data.table but I think it should be trivial. Solution wasn't checked in depth, treat with caution!

Comment: thanks, interesting. map_dbl seems to be a purrr function, so I guess I would need that package. Do you mind explaining what is the idea behind `~which.max(time[time < .x + 3*365.25])) - row_number()+1)` ?

Comment: You can use `sapply` instead of `map_dbl`, with standard function notation. The idea behind the code you copied  is to find the index of last date available  before given date  + 3 years , subtract from it the index from given date (+1) to get a time window, and use this window in the `width` argument

Comment: At first glance it seems my solution and @Uwe's are pretty much the same in their principles. His is cleaner and all data.table though so you'll be better off focusing on it.